# Get S3 image url

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Users can upload images from my app and they get store in `Amazon S3`. I want to use these images in `Chromecast` and I need a `Url` to show the images.

If I do `https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket/img_name.jpg` I get an access denied

How can I get the Url of an image that has already been uploaded?

I know the bucket name and I save the image name for every image locally if that helps any

Comment: How do you upload your images? ACL settings. Whether to expose images as public or private (using signed URLs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bucket name should be a subdomain of `s3.amazonaws.com`:

`https://[bucket].s3.amazonaws.com/img_name.jpg`

You could also use the URL that S3 specifies when you select the file and look at the *Properties* tab in the S3 Management Console.

If you still get an *access denied* message, it's probably the view permission settings. You can make a file public using [this method](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/gettingstarted/latest/awsgsg-intro/gsg-aws-file-public.html), or make the bucket public by doing the following:

1. Click next to the bucket name in the S3 Management Console
2. Expand *Permissions*
3. Click *Add more permissions*
4. Select *Everyone* from the *Grantee* dropdown
5. Press *Save*

(If your file is in a sub folder of the bucket, that path comes before the file: `https://[bucket].s3.amazonaws.com/[folder]/[file]`)